# What is the term in theory/notation when you have notes played over a held note in the same hand?

Tags: theory, musescore, sibelius

eg. Liebestraum no. 3, right hand, bars 1 and 2.

[image: Liebestraum sheet]

also Schubert Impromptu op. 90 no. 3

**Lastly, any idea how this is achieved in Sibelius/Musescore?**

Thanks

Comment: pedal notes? And why/how can the rests be played while the pedal's held on? Never understood that.

Comment: I wouldn't ca it "pedal" because that "C" belongs to both chords - Ab and C7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is nothing else than an arpeggio.

You can notate it like simple 4 voices piano part. (s.below)

In German we call this Akkord-Zerlegung (that is translated in english chord analysis) but this is nothing else than a guitar accompaniment or by a harp. So I'd call it just an arpeggio with a sustained (bass) note.

You'll  have to notate the voices in different layers, but then you'll have to hide the rests in some voices to get a readable sheet product.

Try to notate it the 4 voices in 4 different channels and systems and then mix them together in one grand staff.

**Edit:**

> any idea how this is achieved in Sibelius/Musescore?

Notate the in Sibelius 4 different voices:

or 2 voices in the treble clef and 2 voices in the bass clef:

and if you have all 4 voices in one staff you can separate them later:

Answer (score 2):

You'll need different *voices* to notate these (see [this MuseScore handbook page](https://musescore.org/en/handbook/voices); Lilypond uses the same terminology).

I'm not sure this particular situation has a specific term. It looks like a [melody-dominated homophony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homophony#Melody-dominated_homophony) the right hand is doing a part of the accompanying, usually the job of the left hand.

Another well-known example is the first movement of [Beethoven's Moonlight Sonata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_Sonata_No._14_(Beethoven)), which is described as follows:

> A melody that Hector Berlioz called a "lamentation", mostly by the right hand, is played against an accompanying ostinato triplet rhythm, simultaneously played by the right hand.